# webview inputfield is getting hidden when softinput keyboard is on

Tags: android, webview

I searched online and tried,
`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden"`
`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`
`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`

and I don't have full window theme, still softinput keyboard covers half of the textfield.

Here is my code,

**content.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.quads.quanta.quanta"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_quanta">

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/content_quanta_webview"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**manifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.quads.quanta">
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".quanta"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

I have scrollbar in my website not in app. How to solve it? 
[image: example]